# hist.data.frame not showing histogram plots in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram for all variables in the Boston housing dataset that is available in the MASS package. When I use hist.data.frame function given in the Harrel Miscellaneous package it creates plots but with no values. Is there a way to fix this-
This is the output that I am getting -
[image: histogram of varibles]

Here is my code-

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
boston<-Boston
hist.data.frame(boston);
```

I have already loaded the required packages in R to generate the plots and I am getting no error.

Comment: Everything is squished, not enough vertical space. Make your plot window bigger, or write it to a file so you can specify a big vertical dimension and scroll

Comment: I am new to R. Can you tell how I can make it bigger?

Comment: The same way you make any window on your computer bigger. If you're in RStudio, hover over the borders  between sections and click and drag the dividers to expand the plot area. Or click "Zoom" and click on a corner of the window and drag it bigger. If you already have a separate plotting window, click the corner and drag it bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same code using the library(Hmisc).

`

```
library(MASS)
library(Hmisc)
data(Boston)
boston<-Boston
hist.data.frame(boston)
```

`

Comment: That's is not a good answer, please try to be more descriptive and give code examples.

Comment: how is satisfaction now?? :D